# What are the Benefits of a Two Dimensional Silicon-Based Transistor?

Tags: transistors

It is in the news that [now a group of researchers were able to create a two dimensional silicon-based transistor](http://arstechnica.com/science/2015/02/first-transistor-built-using-two-dimensional-silicon/). A question come to mind that, what are the benefits of a two dimensional silicon-based transistor?

Comment: Probably less steps in production, but since even Si atoms are 3d, I wonder what is really meant by 2d. If you figure that out, I bet the answer reveals itself.

Comment: Only one atom thick, so thinner smart phones will be possible? Seriously, this stuff is pretty far from any practical application, but it might eventually help keep Moore's law valid.

Comment: @PlasmaHH added the link.

Comment: @DaveRose: Given that they are disappointed about its properties, it seems there are no benefits at all, at leasti n the way the built it. Its all something in a lab, no product.

Comment: The benefit to 2D transistors is it gets your name in print in a research journal.

Comment: Diagramming its structure on a piece of paper is easier than with a 3D transistor.

Comment: It seems that the significance wasn't the creation of the transistor, but that it allowed them to perform tests on the silicene. I mean it's in the subtitle - "Graphene's big brother finally kept stable long enough to test". There are no benefits (that I can see) of their 2d transistor, it was only made so they could test the electron flow properties of the silicene.

Answer (score 1):

The significance of 2-D conductors such as graphene and silicene is that because of quantum effects, the electron mobility in these materials is significantly higher than it is in "bulk" semiconductors or even most metals.

This raises the possibility of making active devices (transistors) that can switch much faster than the types of transistors we use today.